# Enforce that .Equals override must compare newly-added properties

Tags: vb.net

I have a class that overrides `Equals`. This class has many properties, and more properties will be added in the future. How can I enforce that, when new properties are added, the `Equals` override must be changed to consider those properties?

I have a partial solution, so you can see what I'm trying to do:

```
Public Class LotsOfProperties
    Public Shared ReadOnly properties As New HashSet(Of String) From {"propertyA", "propertyB"}

    Public Property propertyA As String
    Public Property propertyB As List(Of String)

    Public Overloads Function Equals(ByVal otherObj As LotsOfProperties) As Boolean
        Dim differences As New List(Of String)

        For Each propertyName As String In properties
            Dim meValue As Object = getValueByPropertyName(Me, propertyName)
            Dim otherObjValue As Object = getValueByPropertyName(otherObj, propertyName)
            If Not meValue.Equals(otherObjValue) Then
                differences.Add(propertyName)
            End If
        Next

        Return (differences.Count = 0)

    End Function

    Private Function getValueByPropertyName(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal name As String) As Object
        Dim rtnObj As Object
        Dim pInfo As Reflection.PropertyInfo = obj.GetType.GetProperty(name)
        rtnObj = pInfo.GetValue(obj, Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        Return rtnObj
    End Function
End Class
```

However, this won't work because I want to use SequenceEqual to compare the List property but not to compare the String property. Because I have to use different methods to test equality of each property, I can't just loop through the properties with reflection.

This seems like a common use-case. Is there a simple solution, or do I need to simply trust that future developers will modify `Equals` when adding new properties?

Comment: Do you have any kind of tests around your code? You can write a test which will use reflection and validate your condition.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I still have the fundamental issue of detecting that the property is used in the `Equals` method. How can I use reflection to check that a property is accessed within a specific method?

Comment: It seems to be a process problem, not a code problem.

Comment: @Jack You don't have to check the code. Check the behavior. Create two instances of your class, set all properties to the same value in both instances, except one property. Call `Equals`. If it returns false, that property is used to determine equality. If it returns `true`, it's not.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! So in the test, I should create two objects, make them differ on one property, and test that `Equals` returns `false`? The problem is, I have various property types, so coming up with 2 separate default values will be tricky. Do you have a solution to that problem? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's a test. It does't have to be fancy. You can hardcode the values for each type and make it fail when newly added property has different type.